# NSTextView horizontal scroll would scroll over line number view

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nstextview, nsscrollview

When I enable horizontal scroll in the text view, the content is scrolling above the Vertical Ruler view. It ideally should not overlap the line number view.

Here is how it looks

[image: Text overscroll]

---

To achieve horizontal scroll, I have written an extension on NSTextView

```
public extension NSTextView {
    func wrapText(_ isWrapped: Bool) {
        guard let scrollView = enclosingScrollView else { return }
        scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = !isWrapped
        isHorizontallyResizable = !isWrapped
        let width = isWrapped ? Int(scrollView.contentSize.width) : Int.max
        maxSize = NSSize(width: width, height: Int.max)
        textContainer?.size = NSSize(width: width, height: Int.max)
        textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = isWrapped
    }
}
```

Also

```
textView.enclosingScrollView!.hasVerticalRuler = true
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you create the `NSRulerView` for line numbering? It is somehow transparent, which by default should not be.

Comment: @Tritonal I was able to fix the issue based on your comment.
I had `subviews.first {$0.className == "NSBannerView"}?.isHidden = true`  in the init of my NSRulerView subclass.
Commenting it has fixed the issue.

Comment: Great to hear! `NSRulerView` is pretty difficult to modify, and I've usually just broken things in the process.